# How to move app to sd card when it is not possible?

Tags: applications

Tap Application Manager. Select an app you want to move to the microSD card. If you don't see a Move to SD Card button, the app cannot be moved.

How to move these types of apps to sd card?

Comment: Which android version do you have?

Comment: And no apps can be moved to sd card without root + link2sd or adopting sd card if you have android 6+

Answer (score 0):

on my Asus Zenfone 2, i formatted the micro sd with one partition adopted and second in fat32 and with Apps2SD or Link2SD i always got error "*second partition not found*".

I found that with the swiss-knife "**[Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=it)**" it's very easy and it's working: 
just keep my finger on the app i'd like to move and select "move to adoptable" et tah-dah: my app is moved on the adopted partition on sd.

[image: Titanum backup screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

You can download [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl) and use it to transfer files. However, it requires your phone to be rooted.

Comment: Why is my answer downrated? It is wrong or something?